# Error qr code laravel

Tags: php, laravel, qrcode

Estoy trabajando con la librería de QrCode en laravel 7.0 y en mi servidor local me funciona perfecto pero cuando monte mi sitio en el servidor de producción me genera un error en los códigos Qr. Yo los almaceno en formato svg pero no se por que motivo me los guarda mal aquí dejo una imagen de como me los genera.

[image: Aquí esta el ejemplo de como se genera el svg en producción]

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe este problema?

Comment: Puedes mostrar cual es el error que te muestra en el servidor.

Comment: Es que no me marca ningún error, me genera el archivo svg y si lo guarda en el servidor pero no en forma de Qr si no así como lo muestro en la imagen

Comment: que libreria estás utilizando, y que texto estás tratando de convertir a qr

Comment: Estoy utilizando la librería Simple QrCode y el texto que trato de convertir es un uniqid() de php

Comment: Has verificado si tienes instalada la extensión gd en php, `php -m` para listar las extensiones. Coloca el código que estás utilizando para generar el qr, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: No no he verificado si esta esa extensión que me comentas. El código que utilizo para generar el código qr es el siguiente:
`QrCode::backgroundColor(255, 125, 0, 0.5)->format('svg')->size(100)->generate($folio, 'media/qr/'.$folio.'.svg');`

Comment: La idea que coloques el código, desde que lo generas, hasta que lo imprimes.
El código que colocaste, es para generar un qr y guardarlo en el fichero que tu le indicas.

Comment: Lo has podido solucionar? estoy exactamente en el mismo problema, he generado una nueva pregunta aquí sobre el tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446063/error-en-producci%c3%b3n-con-qrcode-y-laravel

Answer (score 1):

En el repositorio de git encontraron el problema y publicaron un workaround donde cambian comas por puntos cuando generan el svg.

```
sprintf('scale(%s)', str_replace(',','.',round($size, self::PRECISION)))
```

https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode/issues/228

Luego de testear algunas cosas me di cuenta que `setlocale` para español generalmente se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
```

La documentacion de PHP dice que el primer parametro define a que categorias se lo queremos aplicar.
Esto hace que los decimales se separen con coma ',' en vez de por punto y hace que el parametro de scale sean 2 en vez de uno.

> - LC_ALL para establecer todas las siguientes
> - LC_COLLATE para la comparación de cadenas; véase strcoll()
> - LC_CTYPE para la clasificación y conversión de caracteres, por ejemplo strtoupper()
> - LC_MONETARY para localeconv()
> - LC_NUMERIC para el separador decimal (véase también localeconv())
> - LC_TIME para el formato de fecha y hora con strftime()
> - LC_MESSAGES para las respuestas del sistema (disponible si PHP fue compilado con libintl)

En mi caso solo me interesaba que muestre las fechas en español así que solo cambie el primer parámetro por `LC_TIME`

Espero que te haya servido esta solución