# Error en producción con QrCode y Laravel

Tags: laravel, qrcode, qr

Estoy trabajando con la librería de QrCode en laravel 8.0, utilizo php7.3, en local con vagrant y homestead funciona perfecto pero al llevarlo a producción me genera un error en los códigos Qr, los almaceno en formato png que según la [documentación](https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode/es) es correcto pero por algún motivo me los genera mal, aquí dejo una imagen de muestra.

[image: QrCode en producción]

Tengo instalado:

```
"simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.0"
```

luego solo agrego en la vista:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate(strval($order->id))) }}
```

De acuerdo a lo leído en este otro posteo [Error qr code laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428584/error-qr-code-laravel/446048?noredirect=1#comment795225_446048) controlé con ***php -m*** tener la librería GD, y corriendo ***gd_info()*** me devuelve esto:

*array(13) { ["GD Version"]=> string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)" ["FreeType Support"]=> bool(true) ["FreeType Linkage"]=> string(13) "with freetype" ["GIF Read Support"]=> bool(true) ["GIF Create Support"]=> bool(true) ["JPEG Support"]=> bool(true) ["PNG Support"]=> bool(true) ["WBMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["XPM Support"]=> bool(false) ["XBM Support"]=> bool(true) ["WebP Support"]=> bool(false) ["BMP Support"]=> bool(true) ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=> bool(false) }*

Al parecer png está habilitado, pero no me funciona, les agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

UPDATE

He intentado también creando la imagen .svg en el controlador:

```
QrCode::generate(strval($order->id), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/qrcode.svg');
```

Y luego levantarla en la vista pero produce la misma imagen errónea que les mostré al principio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, simplemente tuve que hacer 2 cosas.

Una fue agregar la dependencia de Bacon/BaconQrCode a composer:

```
"bacon/bacon-qr-code": "1.0.3"
```

Y la otra fue bajar de versiones, BaconQrCode me funciona en su versión "1.0.3" y para lograr compatibilidad con Simple-QrCode esta debe trabajar en su versión "^2.0", de esta forma en composer queda:

```
"bacon/bacon-qr-code": "1.0.3",
"simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0"
```

No es lo ideal porque tuve que bajar versiones, BaconQrCode ya tiene su versión 2 y SimpleQrCode su versión 4, pero de momento es la única solución que he encontrado, espero le sirva a alguien más.